# Auto-start KOReader on startup of my jailbroken Kindle Voyage

Tags: jailbreak, kindle, kindle-kdk

I am very new to developing on kindle. I have a kindle voyage in which I want to directly boot into KOReader after the device restarts or at least, auto-launch KOReader after sometime the device turns on. Is that possible. My main goal is to hide the kindle OS and only show the KOReader UI. It would be a life-saver if anyone could help me solve this problem.

I tried finding the solution online but i didn't find it anywhere. Please help me!